# SQL Multiple Left-Join with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I'm working with a total of 4 tables here:

Product Table:
product_id, product_desc

Data 1
product_id, location_id, data1

Data 2
product_id, location_id, data2

Data 3
product_id, location_id, data3

The problem I'm having is not every product_id or location_id is included in each of the data tables. The query I have manages to pull the data correctly for the first data table, but not in instances where the product_id or location_id doesn't exist in data1, but does in data2. I understand this is due to the on condition going back to data1, but I'm not sure how to get the location_nbr in there otherwise. I do have another table that lists all of the location numbers, but these do not correlate anywhere to the item table, so I have no way to join this.

```
select 
    item1.*
    ,coalesce(data1.location_id, data2.location_id, data3.location_id) as location_id
    ,data1.data1
    ,data2.data2
    ,data3.data3

from item1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data1 AS data1
    ON data1.product_id = item1.ksn_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN data2 AS data2
    ON data2.product_id = item1.ksn_id
    and data2.location_nbr = data1.location_nbr

    LEFT OUTER JOIN data3 AS data3
    ON data3.product_id = item1.ksn_id
    and data3.locn_nbr = data1.location_nbr
```

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're asking here, you join everything to `item1`, but `data2` and `data3` join on a `data1` field.  What criteria would you use to join between `data2` and `item1` in the case of the value not being in `data1`?

Answer (score 2):

without seeing the structure of your tables, it is difficult to recommend an exact solution, however, based on the description, you should look into FULL OUTER JOINS which will allow you to include all product_id's and location_id's that are used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Having an example of your desired output may be helpful but in its absence I think a UNION or UNION ALL may accomplish what you are looking for:

```
SELECT Item1.*
     , Data1.*
FROM Item1
LEFT JOIN 
     Data1
  ON Data1.ItemID = Item1.ksn_id
UNION
SELECT Item1.*
     , Data2.*
FROM Item1
LEFT JOIN 
     Data2
  ON Data2.ItemID = Item1.ksn_id
UNION
SELECT Item3.*
     , Data3.*
FROM Item1
LEFT JOIN 
     Data3
  ON Data3.ItemID = Item1.ksn_id;
```